# Who is Yuri Dojoian, Kasparov's analyst in the 90s?

Tags: history, kasparov

Long time ago I read about this strong GM who was one of Kasparov's analysts in the 90s. The thing is that if I search by "Yuri Dojoian" I only get a few results, only in Spanish media, [like this one](https://antoniogude.com/el-reinado-de-kasparov-1/). I'm almost sure there is another way to write his name, but I have no idea how could it be.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the player you are referring to is Yury Dokhoian. According to his [FIDE profile](https://ratings.fide.com/profile/4100476/calculations) and [Olimpbase profile](https://www.olimpbase.org/Elo/player/Dokhoian,%20Yury.html) he has not played competitive chess since 1994. According to his [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yury_Dokhoian) he was Kasparov's second for many years and later started working with Karjakin. [Chessgames.com](https://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessplayer?pid=17837) has 173 of his games.